# Given the width and height of an ellipse find n number of points around the ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

I am looking to find $n$ number of points around an ellipse.
They don't necessarily have to be equidistant.

Similar to what [this forum](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=686288) is asking:

I found several answers that are similar but I am having a hard time expressing it in code.

Comment: Why not evaluate $(a\cos\,t,b\sin\,t)$ at $n$ equispaced values of $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the points $P_k=(x_k,y_k)$, with
$$
x_k=a\cos(2k\pi/n)\\
y_k=b\sin(2k\pi/n)
$$
for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$, and where $a,b$ are the semi-wight and the semi-heigth, respectively.